# How to delegate a whole domain to another server though CloudFlare?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cloudflare, ns-record

I'm facing some difficulties today. I have an Italian domain name, and the Italian Authority (NIC) is very restrictive. For example, you can't have 2 NS records having the same IP address. So in fact, you cannot have your domain on only one server. It's **mandatory** to have 2 servers per domain (or at least, 2 IP addresses) which is very annoying for small projects.

So I've put my domain on CloudFlare (Because they have 2 different IP addresses) and I would like to manage the DNS on my own server.

I tried to put NS records and "glue records"-like but it doesn't work. It works for subdomains if I define them manually in CloudFlare, otherwise it don't.

Can you guys help me ?

Comment: Why do you need to manage DNS on your own server? What is unique about your website that DNS can't be hosted elsewhere? CloudFlare is a great service, and their free tier works well. You need to explain what you're trying to achieve and why for this one.

Comment: Hello Tim, I need to manage my DNS on my server because I have some special features I use. I know what the main purpose of CloudFlare is, I use it for other domains too. But for this case, I just need to use it as a "DNS redirector"

Comment: Ask your domain name registrar. Some of them could provide free secondary DNS service for you.

Comment: "I have some special features I use" is not very convincing on why you need to manage DNS by yourself. It is something sensitive (DNS hosting) as any error could make all your services disappear from the network. We could have a provider handle of it for you.

Comment: Yes I know it is a single point of failure. I'm currently developing an app that needs to register custom DNS records in BIND. I don't want to use CloudFlare as my main DNS provider for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only one server that's a single point of failure, so having a second DNS server that works exactly as you expect isn't going to give you much extra reliability. Use your server as the first name server, and CloudFlare as the second. When you're server is down you're not losing anything that way.

A better solution is to have two servers and use each as a name server. Have a load balancer either on one server (HAProxy / Nginx) or using CloudFlare / CloudFront / etc as a load balancer for the web tier.

I'm curious what you do with DNS that CloudFlare, one of the biggest and most advanced global DNS providers, can't do.

Comment: It's not that CloudFlare cannot do it, it's just that the app I'm developing talks to BIND. Since everything will be self-hosted, the app needs to work without internet access so BIND needs to handle everything. That's why I really would like to use CloudFlare as a "gateway" only. Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is this : DNS request ----> CloudFlare ----> My DNS Server

Comment: I don't think that can be done. I suggest you consider using standard DNS features that can be hosted for you - simple is usually best with technology.